# LINQ for extracting N bottom items (async streams)

Tags: c#, sorting, linq, async-await, extension-methods

`source.Bottom(n, x => x)` should be the same as well known LINQ `source.OrderBy(x => x).Take(n)` but is more memory/run-time efficient as it does not keep all items in memory as `OrderBy` does:

```
public static class BottomN
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Bottom<T, TValue>(
        this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, int number, Func<T, TValue> selector)
        where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        await foreach(var item in source)
        {
            list.Insert(list.BestIndex(item, selector), item);
            if (list.Count > number)
                list.RemoveAt(number);                
        }

        foreach (var item in list)
            yield return item;
    }

    static int BestIndex<T, TValue>(this IList<T> list, T value, Func<T, TValue> selector) 
        where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        return bestIndex(0, list.Count);
        int bestIndex(int s, int e) =>
            s == e ? s :
                selector(list[(s + e) / 2]).CompareTo(selector(value)) > 0 
                ? bestIndex(s, (s + e) / 2) 
                : bestIndex((s + e) / 2 + 1, e);
    }
}
```

To test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Keep_Three()
    {
        var values = new[] { 10, 22, 3, 55, 66, 100, 200, 2 };
        var bottom = await values.ToAsyncEnumerable().Bottom(3, v => v).ToArrayAsync();
        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new int[] { 2, 3, 10 }, bottom);
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong about this question? It would be nice to write a comment after -1 :)

Comment: You should include more information about what this code is supposed to accomplish. I'm assuming the -1 is for the one sentence that fails to describe what this program is.

Comment: Yes, much better already.

Comment: @t3chb0t so how will you tackle this one? :p Didn't Henrik Hansen ask a similar question once?

Comment: @dfhwze I wonder that there is actually only one `=>`... this code could be definitely made harder to read :-] but I love the magic _jambo_ ternary operators. This is another Code Golf like question :-[ I would never let this into production.

Comment: Why don't you call this method something like `LazyOrderBy` or `OrderByAsync` or `LazyOrderByAsync` etc. Admit, you gave it the name `Bottom` to make it more confusing for the user ;-P

Comment: @t3chb0t It does not sort the whole collection - it keeps in memory only best n elements. It is also not so `lazy` - the entire source is being processed. 'Top N' and 'Bottom N' are well known terms in DB world as well as data science of all kind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `where TValue : IComparable<TValue>`

Don't do this. `OrderBy` doesn't require its type parameters to implement this interface like this either. Instead it uses the `IComparer<T>` interface. What's the difference? With `IComparable<T>`, the implementation of the comparison logic is sitting on the class `T` itself. This means that there is one and only one way of ordering elements of `T`. If I wanted to sort them using some customized logic, I would be out of luck.

Instead, `IComparer<T>` is a separate class that compares `T`s. Providing an instance of that interface to the method allows me to use whatever logic I want to order `T`.

But what if I don't want to implement an entire class, but instead want to use `IComparable<T>`? This is where `Comparer<T>.Default` comes to play. This static property provides a default implementation for `IComparer<T>` for `T`, which, if `T` implements `IComparable<T>`, will default to call that logic.

So how would your interface look? We have an overload with the `IComparer<TValue>` argument, and an overload without:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Bottom<T, TValue>(
        this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, int number, Func<T, TValue> selector, IComparer<TValue> comparer)
{
    return Bottom(source, number, selector, Comparer<TValue>.Default);
}

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Bottom<T, TValue>(
        this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, int number, Func<T, TValue> selector, IComparer<TValue> comparer)
{
    // Actual implementation.
}
```

## Binary tree

I think this problem would call for a binary tree, instead of a list that's sorted/ranked continuously. This would you can quickly check whether the item you are iterating would even be in the top-`number` of items in the collection, without having to add and subsequently having to remove it again. The downside is that C# doesn't have a built-in Binary Tree that isn't hidden within the `SortedX` collection set. These classes sadly require unique values in their collections, which isn't guaranteed here.

Alternatively, if you can handle adding another few lines to your solution, you can check if the index returned by `BestIndex` is equal to `number`, and skip adding and removing it from the list if this is the case.

## Code style

This needs to be said. Your code is really compact. It took me multiple reads to figure out what on earth `BestIndex` was actually doing. Docstrings, comments and/or intermediate variables with clear names please. Something as simple as "Returns the rank of `value` in the list by performing a merge-sort style algorithm." is enough to understand its role in `Bottom`.

Comment: Would you think there is a case for using a _Func<TValue, TValue, int>_ instead of _IComparer<TValue>_?

Comment: @dfhwze well, you could implement it like that, but I'd say this is more intuitive, since it matches the other `Linq` and collections API.